# Powerapps canvas app using SP lists. Formula help on Patch function

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a list of records (50) in Table A, [UWT - Training Courses].  I want to add to a button code that will copy all records in Table A to Table B [UWT - Training Courses UWN], adding a column that is a user name.

To add context;

When I click the button it currently has ..SubmitForm(Form1)..  Form1 contains a text box with a persons Name.

I tried changing to,

Collect(colName, "Person A");
SubmitForm(Form1);
Patch('UWT - Training Courses', Defaults('UWT - Training Courses UWN'),{'UWName': colName, 'Line of Business': 'Line of Business'})

I tried

Collect(colName, "Person A");
SubmitForm(Form1_1);
ForAll('UWT - Training Courses', Patch('UWT - Training Courses UWN'),{'UWName': colName, 'Line of Business': 'Line of Business'});

Neither works, any ideas?

Thanks

Stuart

Comment: can you please make your question more readable by formatting your code as code? :)

Comment: Hello

I have manged to sort it.  For Info my final code is below.

ClearCollect(collOne,ShowColumns('UWT-TrainingCourses',"LineofBusiness","Skill","CorrespondingCourse"));
ClearCollect(collTwo,AddColumns(collOne,"UWName",DataCardValue4.Selected.DisplayName));
(SubmitForm(Form1_1);
Patch('UWT-TrainingDetails',ForAll(collTwo As dataSet,dataSet)

sorry not sure how to format as code